# WSL2 - Network adapter configuration issues

Tags: networking, vpn, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'll keep my question pretty general.Please bear in mind I am not a network person.

Here is what I understand happens to network traffic from WSL2.

Network traffic from WSL2 (for example me pinging a machine within a VPN), is sent to the windows gateway, which in turn deals with routing that traffic to the VPN (cisco client in this case) and then that goes to the machine I am trying to access in the VPN. Furthermore, wsl2 network adapter will try to choose ips within 172.16.0.0 or 192.168.0.0.

This work on my machine WHEN WSL2 and the windows adapter are using the network settings of 172.16.0.0 and NOT when it is configured with 192.168.0.0.

I don't understand why this is the case?

To elaborate, the machines within the VPN have ips starting with 192.168. Does it think the machine is within its local network?

Running a traceroute, I see that the traffic is not being sent to my windows adapter.

I just want to understand what is happening during the configuration process (which I believe happens during restarts, shutdowns and sometimes switching over from my work network to my home network) so I can somehow fix this issue and have a better understanding of WSL2 network issues.

Thank you.